# How to construct a TransformManyBlock with a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, dataflow

I'm new to C# TPL and DataFlow and I'm struggling to work out how to implement the TPL DataFlow `TransformManyBlock`. I'm translating some other code into DataFlow. My (simplified) original code was something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<byte[]> ExtractFromByteStream(Byte[] byteStream)
{
    yield return byteStream; // Plus operations on the array
}
```

And in another method I would call it like this:

```
foreach (byte[] myByteArray in ExtractFromByteStream(byteStream))
{
    // Do stuff with myByteArray
}
```

I'm trying to create a `TransformManyBlock` to produce multiple little arrays (actually data packets) that come from the larger input array (actually a binary stream), so both in and out are of type `byte[]`.

I tried what I've put below but I know I've got it wrong. I want to construct this block using the same function as before and to just wrap the `TransformManyBlock` around it. I got an error "The call is ambiguous..."

```
var streamTransformManyBlock = new TransformManyBlock<byte[], byte[]>(ExtractFromByteStream);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has troubles with inferring the types. You need to either specify the delegate type explicitly to disambiguate the call:

```
var block = new TransformManyBlock<byte[], byte[]>(
    (Func<byte[], IEnumerable<byte[]>>) ExtractFromByteStream);
```

Or you can use a lambda expression that calls into that method:

```
var block = new TransformManyBlock<byte[], byte[]>(
    bytes => ExtractFromByteStream(bytes));
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was after. Do you know if one of these methods is preferable over the other?

Comment: @MattL The first one is slightly more efficient, the second one is slightly more readable. So it's up to you to decide which matters more.

Comment: @svick Efficiency all the way. Thanks very much. For my own learning do you have any links you could share that can explain this further?

Comment: @MattL There are some explanations in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6662532/41071).